# Extract 'p' data from 'div' with Class of div = ""

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the data in the div with "" as className followed by p tag.
My html looks like this

```
<div class=""><p>I've been with USAA since 1981 - they've been a good, helpful company and easy to deal with except with making payments on their website. Every time I try to make a payment the website has a problem and I end up calling them. Today, I tried to make a credit card update (same account, different exp. date and code) before I made a payment. The website kept telling me it wouldn't accept the information.</p><p>I called the company to make the payment and was told the system had accepted the information but I couldn't make the payment until tomorrow because of the update. They refused to let me make my payment by phone. 4 times in the past 2 years it wouldn't accept my password, even after I confirmed it by - yes calling in. Other payments have not been accepted for unknown reasons - I've had to call them in. No point having a website if it doesn't work. I avoid calling because it takes so many steps to reach a live person. It's a minor complaint but it happens every time.</p></div></div>
```

I am using Beautifulsoup and my code to extarct this data is :

```
reviewAllList = [row.text for row in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : ""})]
```

However, I am not able to extarct the correct data from the same. Is it that I am missing something? I am using Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda to find all divs with an empty class attribute andthe first child is a `p`

```
rows = [str(row.get_text(strip=True)) for row in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and ("class" not in tag.attrs or not len(" ".join(tag["class"]))) and tag.findChildren()[0].name == "p")]
```

Comment: Zroq you've got to ruin everything :D; I try to help people out you just sweep the ground with all of us. 
Keep it up man, you're awesome !

Comment: All div may not have class. I am getting keyerror. Some div might have been defined without any class.

Comment: I've updated my code to include non classed divs or with empty class name. @DeepaHuddar

Comment: Thanks. :) I tried it the other way. I read the parent div with class and extracted the empty class div tag and the p tag. I was able to get it successfully. Your code also worked well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the text only by saying.

```
sometxt = <div class=""><p>I've been with USAA since 1981 - they've been a good, helpful company and easy to deal with except with making payments on their website. Every time I try to make a payment the website has a problem and I end up calling them. Today, I tried to make a credit card update (same account, different exp. date and code) before I made a payment. The website kept telling me it wouldn't accept the information.</p><p>I called the company to make the payment and was told the system had accepted the information but I couldn't make the payment until tomorrow because of the update. They refused to let me make my payment by phone. 4 times in the past 2 years it wouldn't accept my password, even after I confirmed it by - yes calling in. Other payments have not been accepted for unknown reasons - I've had to call them in. No point having a website if it doesn't work. I avoid calling because it takes so many steps to reach a live person. It's a minor complaint but it happens every time.</p></div></div>
```

and now just `print(sometxt.text)`
if you're only looking for the div class= > "" <
You can print it by `print(sometxt['class'])` remember that you might have to itterate through your findAll with a for loop to do this.(if there's multiple class)

```
**row.text**
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to get the text from the paragraphs.

You could do something like:

```
mydiv = soup.find("div", { "class" : "" })
for p in mydiv.find_all('p'):
    text_list.append(p.get_text())
```

or

```
mydiv = soup.find("div", { "class" : "" })
text = mydiv.find('p').get_text()
```

Can not test right now, but from my experience with BS this should work fine.

Edit: tested and corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried it and i am getting the below error.   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It's get_text(), not getText(), ever since BS4 I think. Give this a try :)


EDIT: I've just tested it and it works with get_text(), will update the answer too.